# Problem with screen evaluation and simple if statement

Tags: python, automation, python-imaging-library

I'm new to stackoverflow, but have one stupid question:

I want to make my computer doing sth if I open up my command promt. I have other plans, but for the moment it just prints out if it's opened or not. Why this code doesn't work??? The computer even prints out the trigger values (12, 12, 12). Is something wrong with my if statement?

Thanks in advance

Output:

```sh
12.12.12
command prompt not opened
12.12.12
command prompt not opened
12.12.12
command prompt not opened
12.12.12
command prompt not opened
12.12.12
command prompt not opened
12.12.12
command prompt not opened
12.12.12
command prompt not opened
12.12.12
command prompt not opened
```

````
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
import time

pixel = (1713, 978) #pixel for evaluation

while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab() #grabs image (like a screenshot)

    color = img.getpixel(pixel) #reads colors of this pixel

    red = str(color[0]) #saves colors in three variables to make evaluation easier
    green = str(color[1])
    blue = str(color[2])

    print(red + "." + green + "." + blue) #prints color in rgb

    if red == 12 and green == 12 and blue == 12: #if all three colors are 12 -> print that cmd is opened
        print("command promt opened")
        time.sleep(5)
    else: #else print that cmd isn't opened
        print("command prompt not opened")```
````

Comment: your storing the colour as a string, then comparing it to an int. `"12" == 12` will return false. Either store the colors as int and compare them to ints, or store them as strings and compare them to strings

Comment: Thanks, it works now! 
I simply wrap it to this: 

if int(red) == 12 and int(green) == 12 and int(blue) == 12:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
if int(red) == 12 and int(green) == 12 and int(blue) == 12:
```